# Does javax @Transactional use a database-level transaction when working with a relational database driver that supports transactions?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-transactions

My question is about the implementation of javax.transaction.@Transactional when paired with a JPA implementation like Hibernate and a relational database driver like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

- Does the JPA provider use a datbase-level transaction (exposed by the JDBC driver), or manage the transaction in the JPA implementation itself?
- Is the connection kept alive for the duration of the transaction?

Comment: How do you envision this working without using a database-level transaction? It would be impossible to support the necessary guarantees without cooperation of the database.

Comment: "It would be impossible to support the necessary guarantees without cooperation of the database." When you put it that way, it seems so obvious. I suppose I envisioned a Hibernate session-level transaction where it managed and validated each operation before flushing. But it could never guarantee the flush would succeed. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The flushing is not the only concern, also think about visibility guarantees of transactions, and thinks like update conflicts, etc, also considered multi-homed applications, or multiple applications sharing a database, etc.

Comment: Those are all scenarios I hadn't considered. Appreciate the thoughtful response.

Comment: Then lets say, I am using a db which does not support transactions then should we expect the compile to fail? That could be a fair expectations, but I don't think this will happen. It will go unnoticed, with no explicit error thrown, if the underlying db is changed to one which does not support transaction?